# Owl carousel - фиксированный Width для items

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Можно ли как-нибудь задать фиксированный размер для items в owl-carousel?

Comment: .item{
      width: 100% !important;
    }

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статья - [AutoWidth](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autowidth.html)

**1) Вариант.**

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:true,
    autoWidth:true,
    items:4
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 10rem;
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.owl-carousel .item h4 {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0rem;
}
.owl-carousel {
    margin: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
 

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" >
    <div class="item" style="width:250px"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:100px"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:500px"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:100px"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:50px"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:250px"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:120px"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:420px"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:120px"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:300px"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:450px"><h4>12</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:220px"><h4>13</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:150px"><h4>14</h4></div>
    <div class="item" style="width:600px"><h4>15</h4></div>
</div>
```

---

**2) Вариант.**

```
.item{ 
    width: 100% !important; 
}
```